# GetUserProfileByName not taking the right value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I have Leave Form that is created in InfoPath and Published it to SharePoint 2013. I followed [this link](https://samsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/infopath-get-the-current-user-without-writing-code/)  to take the current logged information.

However there is an issue on taking the value. 
Let say I have 2 users:

```
   User1    -   Robert
   User2    -   Mike
```

When user1 is login, it shows the correct FirstName which is Robert but when user2 logs in, the FirstName shows still Robert.

I am not sure what i am my missing. Hope someone could help me the right direction on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: In Addition, i already created Secure Store Service Application as group and added users to members. After that i  setup the Set Credentials. What it seems to me whoever the username i put on Set Credentials (Windows Username) that user profile will appear on the form and not the profile of current login.

Comment: which user account are you feeding into the data connection for GetUserProfileByName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to feed the current user name into the GetUserProfileByName query field and refresh the query. Then you can get the current user's data from the returned record.

Take a look at Clayton Cobb's post. https://claytoncobb.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/

Once you manage to work through that, you should be able to get any user profile challenge sorted.